# iBatis resultClass result variable is null

Tags: mysql, ibatis

Sorry, poor English level,
Forgive me stackoverflow.

The company is using the "ANT" script generation tool generated SQL MAPPER, the use of 'resultClass', the return of the object data is empty. Sql in the database is no problem. And other people use the same wording, can not get the correct results.

PS: If I do not use resultClass, just return a count to get the result

ANT script：

```
<operation name="queryAgentLoanCount" multiplicity="many" resultClass="com.bench.common.dal.result.AgentLoanCountResult">
    <extraparams>
        <param name="agentNo" javatype="java.lang.String"/>
    </extraparams>
    <sql>
        SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM bops_agent_loan_record
    </sql>
    <sqlmap>
        <![CDATA[
        SELECT COALESCE(SUM(tt.LOAN_AMT),0) TT_AMT ,COALESCE(COUNT(t.ID),0) TT_SUM
        FROM bops_agent_loan_record t LEFT JOIN bops_loan_request tt
                ON t.REQ_NO = tt.REQ_NO
        WHERE tt.LOAN_TYPE IN ('P1024', 'P1002', 'P5060')
                AND tt.STATE IN ('SELLING', 'BACKING', 'BACKED', 'OVERDUE')
                AND t.AGENT_NO = #agentNo#
        ]]>
    </sqlmap>
</operation>
```

Generated SQLMAPPER:

```
<select id="MS-AGENT-LOAN-RECORD-QUERY-AGENT-LOAN-COUNT" resultClass="com.bench.common.dal.result.AgentLoanCountResult">
    SELECT COALESCE(SUM(tt.LOAN_AMT),0) TT_AMT ,COALESCE(COUNT(t.ID),0) TT_SUM
        FROM bops_agent_loan_record t LEFT JOIN bops_loan_request tt
                ON t.REQ_NO = tt.REQ_NO
        WHERE tt.LOAN_TYPE IN ('P1024', 'P1002', 'P5060')
                AND tt.STATE IN ('SELLING', 'BACKING', 'BACKED', 'OVERDUE')
                AND t.AGENT_NO = #agentNo#
</select>
```

resultClass:

```
public class AgentLoanCountResult extends BaseDO {

private Long ttSum;

private Double ttAmt;

public AgentLoanCountResult() {
}

public AgentLoanCountResult(Long ttSum, Double ttAmt) {
    this.ttSum = ttSum;
    this.ttAmt = ttAmt;
}

public void setTtSum(Long ttSum) {
    this.ttSum = ttSum;
}

public Long getTtSum() {
    return ttSum;
}

public Double getTtAmt() {
    return ttAmt;
}

public void setTtAmt(Double ttAmt) {
    this.ttAmt = ttAmt;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should map the columns in your result object. Try something like this

```
<resultMap id="resultMapName" class="com.your.object">
    <result property="ttSum" column="TT_SUM" />
    <result property="ttAmt" column="TT_AMT" />
</resultMap>
<select id="MS-AGENT-LOAN-RECORD-QUERY-AGENT-LOAN-COUNT" resultMap="resultMapName">
    SELECT COALESCE(SUM(tt.LOAN_AMT),0) TT_AMT ,COALESCE(COUNT(t.ID),0) TT_SUM
        FROM bops_agent_loan_record t LEFT JOIN bops_loan_request tt
                ON t.REQ_NO = tt.REQ_NO
        WHERE tt.LOAN_TYPE IN ('P1024', 'P1002', 'P5060')
                AND tt.STATE IN ('SELLING', 'BACKING', 'BACKED', 'OVERDUE')
                AND t.AGENT_NO = #agentNo#
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, if not forced to use ANT to generate SQL MAPPER, your solution is correct.
I change the SQL directly:
SELECT COALESCE（SUM（tt.LOAN_AMT），0）ttSum，COALESCE（COUNT（t.ID），0）ttAmt